# Failed to read schema file from document

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xsd, schema, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal an incoming XML object with a schema. I created a schema with `schemagen` command from java object and added some minOccur and maxOccur attributes.

I put the schema in src/main/resources. This is the error:
`Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/Users/cen/Desktop/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-sy/standalone/deployments/vloga-ear.ear/vloga-service.jar/VlogaData.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.`

Code:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File schemaFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("VlogaData.xsd").getFile());
            if (schemaFile.canRead()) LOG.info("can read");
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaFile); 
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Schema xsd (tried with and without xml tag, with xsd namespace, same result):

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="VlogaData" type="VlogaData"/>

  <xs:complexType name="VlogaData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="idVloge" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="idPriloge" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="imeVloge" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="verzija" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="vrstaPriloge" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="datumOblikovanja" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="datumZadnjeSpremembe" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="lastnik" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="kljucneBesede" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="priloga" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I determine which reason of the three is it? File path seems allright (I unpacked the jar and schema is there). "can read" is not output from logger so the file can't be read.. but why? And the third reasoning should be allright too since I tried three different schemas and nothing works.

Comment: Whats the full-path of the schema file, relative to the jar content? the classloader.getresource is looking in the same dir as the class. if it is at the base of the dir, you better preceed it with /VlogaData.xsd. In the meantime, i would also go for Classloader.getResourceAsStream.

Comment: Schema is directly inside the jar. I tried with /VlogaData but error is exactly the same. I saw the code examples using a stream but schema constructor expects a file so I'd try not to convert from streams to a file if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the file cannot be read because it is inside a jar, then `file:/C:/Users/cen/Desktop/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-sy/standalone/deployments/vloga-ear.ear/vloga-service.jar/VlogaData.xsd` isn't really a file.

As `SchemaFactory.newSchema` can receive an `URL` I'd suggest you to do the simpler:

```
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(classLoader.getResource("VlogaData.xsd"));
```

It worked in a little test in my environment.